# How to use airdrop filter in parameters of alchemy's getNFT api

Tags: nft, erc-721, alchemy

[image]

hello ! I have a question while using the alchemy api.
As shown in the picture above, it says tha can put **"Airdrop"** in the parameter **"includeFilters[]"** of the api. I'm running an Airdrop event, so I'm very interested in this feature. Can anyone tell me how to use it?

What data should I put in the NFT for the alchemy api filter to work?

Answer (score 0):

According to the example (for Node language) on the doc:

```
const sdk = require('api')('@alchemy-docs/v1.0#z93mjsc2xlb2w41kg');

sdk.server('https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/nft/v2');
sdk.getNFTs({
    owner: 'vitalik.eth',
    withMetadata: 'false',
   'includeFilters[]': 'AIRDROPS', // this is how you use it
   apiKey: 'demo'
})
.then(({ data }) => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Inside the getNFTs method, you pass in the metadata that contains `includeFilters[]` as the key and `AIRDROPS` as the value.

Comment: As in the example below, if AIRDROP is added to the NFT's metadata, will the filter be applied?
Or is there another way?
Example :
{
"name":"name",
"description":"description",
"image":"img url",
"ARIDROP":"this si aridrop nft"
}

Comment: No, "AIRDROPS" is the value of the key "includeFilters[]". The word "AIRDROPS" cannot be used as the key because the filter is not built that way. By using "includeFilters[]" and setting the value to "AIRDROPS", you will only get the NFTs that were air-dropped. It's like setting a bool value to true or false. You cannot set the key as "true", or "false", but only as a value of the key "bool". That is how the "includeFilters[]" work.